# .toggle() does not work with IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, toggle

I want to show some information when hitting a link as you can find here: http://jsfiddle.net/t4f8yer0/1/

html:

```
<a href="#" class="more">show more</a> <br>
<div class="toggle">
this is more
</div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle").css('display','none');

  $( ".more" ).click(function() {
    $(event.target).next().next().toggle( "slow" );
  });
});
```

This works for chrome and IE edge but not for IE9 or IE10. Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Thanks Woodsy, j08691 and Ted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$(event.target);
```

use:

```
$(this);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/t4f8yer0/2/)**

Different versions of IE have issues that jQuery normalizes, such as what you're seeing with event.target.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code to reference the `toggle` div class and it seems to be working.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").css('display','none');

    $( ".more" ).click(function() {
        $(".toggle").toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: This works but the probem is that if you have more than one such element it will have effect on all of the other as well. Therefore this is not the perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

For this HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="more" data-target="#more1">show more</a> <br>
<div id="more1" class="toggle" style="display:none;">
    this is more
</div>
```

This JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( ".more" ).click(function() {
        var tgt = $(this).attr('data-target');
        $(tgt).toggle( "slow" );
    });
});
```

This allows you to set a target for toggling. [See it work here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4f8yer0/3/)